# Best container for storing tile map nodes?

Tags: c++, path-finding

I'm programming an isometric 2D scenario, in which I'll have to use A* pathfinding. Is it better to have a vector to store all tile nodes (and everytime I request "West-South adjacent node" calculate it and check if it exist with some maths), or rather I directly prepare all nodes with pointers to 9 of adjacent nodes, and zero them if it's a bound? This option is a little bit memory consuming, but is it worth?

What is best way to store tile map nodes in general, std::vector, std::list, custom?

Comment: Do you have so many nodes that it would push memory bounds to make each node store 9 neighbor-pointers? If not, just do it. It would make the pathfinding way faster, at little cost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a grid map, An (one dimensional) array/vector may do the job.
The "math" to compute/check neighbours is very simple.

You may add "fake" tiles around your map to simplify/optimize the check.

So for a 3x3 map, you construct a 5x5 map with unpassable tile on the border.

```
XXXXX
X...X
X...X
X...X
XXXXX
```

North/South : index +/- 5

East/West: index +/- 1

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the option you gave of each node storing 9 pointers, each to a neighbor. Unless you have a *huge* number of nodes, the memory usage would be negligible on today's hardware, and the pathfinding would be way faster if you could easily return neighbors to nodes, rather than doing a search for *every single node* you have to find.

In short, the memory usage will not be *that* high, and pathfinding would be faster than with other schemes.

Comment: What do you mean with huge? I'd have at least 100 x 100 nodes, 9 each is 90.000 pointers. And I may even need 250x250

Comment: Doing the math for the bigger grid, 250x250x9x4 (number of bytes to store all the neighbor pointers) is about 2.15 megabytes. I'm having trouble figuring out how much memory a program _can_ allocate in total, but it is _way_ more than 2.15 Mb.

Comment: @freesoul So, as I said earlier, if you are memory constrained, then don't do it. Otherwise, do it!

Comment: With a single char, he can store in each cell the "neighbour topology" (corner NW, NE, SW, SE; Edge N,S,E,W or center) if he really want to avoid to check at runtime the neighbours.